# C# Regex Matching, Name

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I’m horrible at regular expresses and could use a bit of help.

I get string like `“Tell:IIDString: 456456456:Somebody's Name "`, however sometime the number is a zero. Also the name always ends with a space. I want to extract the name and thought Regex would be the way to go, but I can’t seem to get it to work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string txt = "Tell:IIDString: 456456456:Somebody's Name ";
    // txt = "Tell:IIDString: 0:Somebody's Name ";'
    Match m = Regex.Match(txt, @"Tell:IIDString: \d+:([A-z\']+)\.\w", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think `\.\w` at the end causing problem. also put space in `[A-z\' ]` (because spaces can be between names) and print `m.Groups[1].Value` instead.

Comment: I tried  "Tell:IIDString: \d+:([A-z\' ]+)"  and it will match, but not extract the name

Comment: Well you can split the string and get the name value without regex if your input string format is always same.  string txt = "Tell:IIDString: 456456456:Somebody's Name ";
 string name = txt.Split(':')[3];

Comment: Thank the groups value works. I know I can trim the result, but it there a way to do trim the ending space with the expression?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(m.Value);` will print whole string because its the first match. you are using group in your pattern `([A-z\']+)` so instead you have to print `Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value)`

Comment: just put space at the end of pattern. `"Tell:IIDString: \d+:([A-z\' ]+) "`

Comment: Hi, did my answer below help? If not, please consider clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex that will match the whole sample input, capture the name and trim it:

```
^Tell:IIDString:\s*\d+:(?<name>[A-Z' ]+?)\s*$
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/80RPdk):

```
string txt = "Tell:IIDString: 456456456:Somebody's Name ";
Match m = Regex.Match(txt, @"^Tell:IIDString:\s*\d+:([A-Z' ]+?)\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value); // Note the group is referred by its name
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - Start of string
- `Tell:IIDString:` - literal sequence of the given characters
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace symbols
- `\d+:` - 1 or more digits followed with a `:`
- `(?<name>[A-Z' ]+?)` - a named capture group thay we'll refer to later by the name, matching 1 or more Latin characters, apostrophe and a literal space (replace with `\s` if there may be any whitespace or `\p{Zs}` if only horizontal whitespace is allowed)
- `\s*$` - 0 or more whitespace symbols at the end of the string (`$` is the end of line anchor).